# Hive -f is creating new sessions each time

Tags: hive, hortonworks-data-platform

I have a framework written in shell , where it calls multiple hql files.

hive -f file1.hql

hive -f file2.hql

hive -f file3.hql

Each hive -f command creating new sessions and taking lot of time to execute the command. Many times the actual query in these files will ran quickly, but the majority of the time going for new session creation.

Deoe hive support session polling/ or any other mechanism to create a session once in the hql file and reuse it during all other hive -f calls ?

Comment: The good way: append new queries to a single file, then finally execute all queries in one batch. The bad way: what you are doing now. The ugly way: use a Linux **named pipe** so that `hive` executes each query as soon as it is created, cf. http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/using-named-pipes-fifos-bash

Comment: While narrating the question , i tried to keep it so simple. In my actual case the hive command are not exist in the framework one by one 
(Sequential) , there is other logic in between, and I cannot keep all hql content in to one file and run it.

Answer (score 0):

As I know it isn't possible. At best you could consider merging your hql files into one batch file.
As alternative and recommended approach you could consider switching to HiveServer2 service e.g. using https://github.com/cloudera/impyla in Python.

Comment: Why _<censored>_ Python??? Just use the `beeline` command (the JDBC thin client) instead of `hive` (the deprecated, fat client)

Comment: As of me Beeline shines for interactive workflow but I couldn't recommend it for programmatic access.